# React pro sidebar use

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I start coding in React and I wanted to use react-pro-sidebar: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pro-sidebar

I precise it is the first time I use such a package.
I followed the instructions and wrote the following code in App.js:

```
import classes from './App.module.css';
import { ProSidebar, Menu, MenuItem, SubMenu } from 'react-pro-sidebar';
import 'react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css';

<ProSidebar>
  <Menu iconShape="square">
    <MenuItem>Dashboard</MenuItem>
    <SubMenu title="Components">
      <MenuItem>Component 1</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Component 2</MenuItem>
    </SubMenu>
  </Menu>
</ProSidebar>;

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={classes.App}>
        <ProSidebar/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Why this code is not displaying the sidebar on my app ? And what should I do to display the sidebar ?

Thank you very much for your answer, I'm sure it should be obvious but it is not for me and your answer will help me understand much more how does it works.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're not very familiar with React, that's why you just followed the documentation blindly. They've just wrote the imports part and JSX part without showing how it looks while it is being wrapped into React Class

Check fixed code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { ProSidebar, Menu, MenuItem, SubMenu } from 'react-pro-sidebar';
import 'react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css';

const sidebar = <ProSidebar>
  <Menu iconShape="square">
    <MenuItem>Dashboard</MenuItem>
    <SubMenu title="Components">
      <MenuItem>Component 1</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Component 2</MenuItem>
    </SubMenu>
  </Menu>
</ProSidebar>;

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {sidebar}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```